# How to compare stored time in HH:MM with current time?

Tags: java, android, jodatime

I tried using Joda-Time library to compare stored time in string `"hh:mm"` format with current time. I used following code but the output is random. Its output is not right.

```
LocalTime now = LocalTime.now();
LocalTime limit;
limit = LocalTime.parse(date); //date is any string data in format "hh:mm", e.g "14:30"  

if( now.isAfter( limit )){
    ans = date+"is Past or Present Time";
}else{
    ans = date+" is Future time";
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what you provided as input and got a wrong output ?

Comment: I used String as  an input in "HH:mm" format like "08:30". I tried with different inputs, some get right answer and some doesn't.

Comment: What do you mean by *"output is random"* and what are you expecting as output? `LocalTime.now()` will give you the current time in the machine the code is running (using the default **TimeZone**). Have you checked what time is `now` to know if the output is really wrong?

Comment: Yes Hugo,I checked it, so I'm asking if there is any problem with my code?
suppose i gave input time(limit)= "14:50" and current system time (now)="13:50" then
output of "now.isAfter( limit )" method was supposed to be "false" because "13:50"  doesn't come after "14:50" .
But the output is random.

Comment: I can't reproduce this error, for me it works (including your last example). Maybe the problem is in another part of the code, I don't know...

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to get current date:

```
Date date = new Date();
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmm");
LocalTime now=LocalTime.parse(format.format(date));
```

Then try to compare, hope it will help you! Because you are using  `LocalTime.now()` this will also have time default time zone in it.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this may be useful for you .

```
public  void DateComparision(String dateString) {
    try {

        //"yyyy-MM-dd" --> Here you can take your date format

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

        // Get date object from given string
        String givenDate = dateString;
        Date date1 = null;
        try {
            date1 = sdf.parse(givenDate);
        } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Get date object from current date
        String currentDate = sdf.format(new Date());
        Date date2 = null;

        try {
            date2 = sdf.parse(currentDate);
        } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (date1.compareTo(date2) < 0) {

            // Past date

        } else if (date1.compareTo(date2) > 0) {

            // Futer date

        } else {

            // Today date

        }

    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome brother.